# Close all Responsive-accordion Tabs on small screen? (Foundation 6.3)

Tags: tabs, zurb-foundation, accordion, responsive

So I'm having a really hard time figuring out why I can't collapse my accordion tabs using the Foundation 6.3 responsive tabs (https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/responsive-accordion-tabs.html). I am trying to use their javascript reference to implment: (https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/accordion.html#up).

This only seams to work for the accordion but not responsive accordions tabs. 
Code Pen to demonstrate:https://codepen.io/jinch/pen/RQxQNG

```
//This code only collapses the "Reugular Accordion" and NOT a responsive Accordion?
$('#regulare-accordion').foundation('up', $('#regulare-accordion .accordion-content'));

//This code does not working for the the "Responsive Accordion Tab"?
$('#responsive-tab-accordion').foundation('up', $('#responsive-tab-accordion .accordion-content'));
```

Does anyone know of a reason or solution if using the responsive tabs? I need to close all on small screens if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far the responsive tab accordion component does not implement the methods of the used plugins.

You can either collapse them with CSS or clonse the methods of the accordion plugin and execute their code.

See https://github.com/zurb/foundation-sites/pull/10961 which is not yet implemented.